# Compiler Directives - Delphi Versions

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, compiler-directives

I have a unit I wrote in Delphi 7 some time ago, and have just had the fun (pain) of converting to Delphi XE (Unicode).

The Unit works fine after some trouble, I am now trying to make this unit compatible with different Delphi Versions should I ever need to switch IDE back to Delphi 7 whilst updating some other code.

I only have Delphi 7 and Delphi XE, but from what I gather code written in Delphi 1 to Delphi 2007 will compile, but code from Delphi 2009 and above will be Unicode.

...Anyway, in the Unit I am separating the non-unicode and unicode like so:

```
{$IFDEF VER150} //Delphi 7
// code
{$ELSE IFDEF VER220} //Delphi XE
// code
{$ENDIF}
```

How do I modify the compiler directive so the rules apply to multi versions? For example something like:

```
{$IFDEF VER80,  //D1
        VER90,  //D2
        VER100, //D3
        VER120, //D4
        VER130, //D5
        VER140, //D6
        VER150, //D7}
```

This would then cover all Delphi versions should I distribute the source or .dcu unit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wonder if the simplest approach in this instance is to switch behaviour on the `UNICODE` conditional. This conditional is defined if and only if you are using a Unicode version of Delphi, i.e. in Delphi 2009 and later. The big advantage of this is that it is future proof—you don't need to update your code every time a new Delphi is released. What's more, the conditional switch will be far more readable since it will clearly express the intent.

The Delphi documentation has an excellent [topic](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29#Predefined_Conditionals) listing all the pre-defined conditionals. The full list of version conditionals is also [linked](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Versions) from there.

Comment: +1, you were faster. If OP wants only to separate the code by Unicode version of Delphi then `UNICODE` directive is the exact one. There are also CompilerVersion and RTLVersion for determining the current Delphi version.

Comment: ... unless someone has been using `UNICODE` in the past. For example to accommodate the lack of Unicode support within Delphi itself ;) ... still, +1 ... your solution seems cleaner if it can be guaranteed that `UNICODE` is not already used.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED In that case the code that defines and uses a custom conditional named `UNICODE` should be changed.

Comment: @David: I'm not sure I agree. In C/C++ it has been customary for certain entities (defines and functions) to start with two leading underscores if they are compiler-specific. Borland (et. al.) should have made such rules long ago. They're changing the rules and breaking the code all the time. Particularly the Unicode support is/was a mess in that regard. I still don't understand how committed Delphians can remain so calm ;) ... I've kind of left all of that behind me some time ago, although I still use Delphi at times.

Comment: @STATUS Be that as it may, it is what it is and if Emba define `UNICODE` then you need not to, whether you like it or not.

Comment: @David thanks for the information, using UNICODE directive is much more better :)

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is actually to look at one of the many JEDI projects, http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/ for example and look at how they do it. They have common include files that contain exactly the details you are interested in. JVCL is another good choice ...

Comment: Yes the jvcl inc is perfect. There 's just every compiler directive to code some version-specific sections.